# post request using oak in deno with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, deno, oak

I'm new to deno, and I'm trying to create a post request with oak following this tutorial by freecodecamp (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQUy8ENesGY). And I realized that many things changed and it took me hours to find those many things using oak.

But now I'm stuck in using the User model to create a new user (at the 2 hours and 33 mins in the video). It gives me this error:-

> Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type
> 'Promise': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag]

Here's my code:-

authcontroller.ts:-

```
import { RouterContext, hash, compare } from "../deps.ts";
import User from "../models/user.model.ts";

class AuthController {

    async register(ctx: RouterContext){
        const result = ctx.request.body({ type: "form-data" });
        const data = (await result.value.read()).fields;
        const name = data['name'];
        const password = data['password'];
        const email = data['email'];

        let user = User.findOne({email});
        if (user){
            ctx.response.body = { message: "Email is already used!" };
            ctx.response.status = 409;
        }

        const hashedPassword = hash(password);
        // user = new User({name, email});
        ctx.response.status = 201;
        console.log(data);
    }

    login(ctx: RouterContext){
        ctx.response.body = "This is new login"
    }
}

const authController = new AuthController();
export default authController;
```

user.model.ts:-

```
import usersCollection from "../mongo.ts";

class User {
    public id: string;
    public name: string;
    public email: string;
    public password: string;

    constructor({ id='', name='', email='', password=''}){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    static findOne(params: object){
        return usersCollection.findOne(params);
    }
}


export default User;
```

router.ts:-

```
import { Router, RouterContext } from "./deps.ts";

import authController from "./controllers/authController.ts";


const router = new Router();


router.get("/", (ctx) => {
    ctx.response.body = "New Hello world!"
});

router.post("/api/login", authController.login);
router.post("/api/register", authController.register);

export default router;
```

I want to know the best practice of using the model, and whether if I have to use the Interface type or not.

And also, if there's a better way to write the post request, please do tell me.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `let user = await User.findOne({email});`

Comment: Thanks.. if you have any comment or improvement on my code, do tell me...